# Serving Angular 2/4 code with express

Tags: angular, express

In angular 1 I was able to have a single project for both front end and back end because I could use the express feature to serve up the front end code

```
app.use('/frontEnd', express.static('frontend'));
```

This approach has an error because currently with the angular 4 quick start seed the index.html is not in the root front end folder but the src inside the root front end folder. So to account for that I tried:

```
app.use('/frontEnd', express.static('frontend/src'));
```

That "works" but when you pull up `localhost:8080/frontEnd` it breaks.

**QUESTION**: What is the work around for this?

**ALTERNATE QUESTION**: If this is no longer available, 1. is there a way to have a single project for both ends or 2. Is the proper procedure to just keep both side separated in their own projects?

Comment: Does this tutorial help? https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

Comment: That tutorial worked! I also like that it gives high level reasons on why things are that way.

Answer (score 0):

Because of History API, Express need to catch all request made and serve the `index.html` then let Angular handle routes.

So the snippet you should use in your Express app is :

```
// Include the path module
include path from 'path'

// Specify your static path
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/src/assets')));

// Then catch all requests made to http://localhost:8080/frontEnd
app.get('/frontEnd/*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/src/index.html'));
});
```

Now when you gonna load static such images, scripts, etc. the path `/assets` gonna load static from `frontend/src/assets`. If you don't specify an asset path, every asset request will return index.html !

Additionally, when you'll go prod, think about [server-side rendering](https://github.com/angular/universal). :)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/universal is Angular 2, not 4. And currently the one should think twice before thinking of using Angular server side rendering in production. It's not for faint-hearted.

Comment: Yes, I've heard they merged universal in Angular 4 but OP asks for Angular 2 / 4 so I put this repo. The README.md in it is enough clear to indicate what to use depending on the ng version.

Comment: This loads the page but it loads with errors. They are a bunch of "failed to load resource" errors.

Comment: Edited, hope that would fix your problem !